# how can i use \d in php pdo to print the tables out of a database in progress?

Tags: pdo

\d from textarea

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($mytextarea);

    echo $mytextarea;
    if($stmt->execute()== true)
        {
            echoTableFromResults($stmt);
        } 

        $conn = null;
```

I want to be able to print the tables in my progresql database from my website, but I do not know how to get the result as \d works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where tableowner ='username'
```

I found the answer, thanks.